# How do you teleport multiple entites forward at once in 1.13?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to setup a repeating command block that would teleport every entity with a specific name ***x*** blocks forward on x/z axis.
In versions before 1.13 you could do this with the following command set on repeat:

`/tp @e[name=Name] ~1 ~ ~`

However as 1.13 formatting changed, I cannot find a command that would work the same way.
If you know the command that would do this task please let me know!
I have tried commands similar to the following:

`/execute at @e[name=Name] run teleport @e[name=Name] ~1 ~ ~`

This was the closest I could get but it only teleports every entity with that name infront of one of them. 
I had been trying to find a way to perform this simple thing for over a hour, including searching for answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a bit of testing and thinking to figure this out. Since using `@s` didn't work, I came up with a not very pretty, but working command:

```
/execute at @e[name="Name"] run tp @e[name="Name",distance=0] ~1 ~ ~
```

This is the command that you had, but with the `distance` tag added. Now, every entity with that name will teleport only itself instead of every other entity with the same name.

Comment: Well that really did work, this was what i was looking for. Thanks for the find

Comment: @user232211 Feel free to mark one of the answers as accepted, so the question is considered solved.

Answer (score 1):

You used `@e` twice, so you split up the command between all entities twice. You teleported **every entity** to **every entity**. This throws all your poor animals around the entire world many times in less than a second until they finally land at whatever spot happens to be the last one.

The solution is indeed `@s`, but that only works properly if "myself" actually means the entities you want, which you can change with `/execute as`:

```
/execute as @e[name="Name"] at @s run teleport ~1 ~ ~
```